# Octobercms child relationship of relationships

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

Im working in a octobercms plugin and i have the following models in it:

- Houses
- Pays
- Owners

In Houses model i have the following relationship:

```
public $hasManyThrough = [
      'owner' => [
        'Author\Plugin\Models\Owner',
        'table' => 'author_plugin_houses_owners',
        'key' => 'houses_id',
        'otherKey' => 'owners_id'
      ]
    ];
```

this relationship has a intermediate table 'author_plugin_houses_owners':

```
+------------+-------------+--------+
| hoses_id   |  owners_id  | active |
+------------+-------------+--------+
```

And in Pays model i have the following relationship:

```
public $belongsTo = [
        'houses' => ['Author\Plugin\Models\Houses']
];
```

this model corresponds to a table like this:

```
+----+----------+---------+-------+------+
| id | hoses_id | amounth | payed | debt |
+----+----------+---------+-------+------+
```

in the table i have a column "houses_id", the question is, how i can access to "owner" relationship declared in "Houses" model since "Pays" model? i need access to it because i need printed "owner_name" on list view in the plugin backend.

owner table:

```
+----+------------+--------+
| id | owner_name | active |
+----+------------+--------+
```

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that `Pay` belongs to only one house.

```
public $belongsTo = [        
    'house' => ['Author\Plugin\Models\Houses'] 
  // ^ you can use house instead houses for relation name
];
```

Now we can access owner with relation chain

```
$payModel->house->owner
```

Since `you made relation hasMany` one house can have multiple `owners` [ **hasManyThrough** ]

so this will return you a list of `owners`.

As in `list view` you need to use it, You can define `partial` type column

```
columns:
    id:
        label: id
        type: number
        searchable: true
        sortable: true

    .... other fields ...

    owner_name:
        label: Owner
        type: partial
        path: $/hardiksatasiya/demotest/models/sort/_ownername_column.htm
```

> Make sure to replace the path with your own plugin author name and path.

Now inside partial, you can write your actual logic [ this must be in PHP not in twig ]

```
<?php
// this is hasmany relation so we expect multiple owners
$owners = $record->house->owner;
$ownerArr = [];
foreach($owners as $ownr) {
    $ownerArr[] = $ownr->owner_name;
}
$output = implode($ownerArr, ', ');
?>

<?php echo $output ?>
```

> If there is only one owner it will show `Hardik` one name only if there are multiple owners it will show `Hardik, Noe` comma separated values.

[image]

if any doubts please comment.

Comment: one thing more, if i want turn this column to a searchable column it works or i need do another functionality? thanks.

Comment: no i think it will not directly work you may need to extend list query for that, if i get more time i will post how to do that. but this we have to do manually as its deep relational field :)